# android dropbox api file upload

Tags: android, dropbox

I am implementing dropbox integration in my android app.I have done file uploading i.e my file is uploaded successfully on dropbox but how can i check if a same file exists on dropbox and create a new copy of the file on dropbox.Please help me

my code for upload is below:

```
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(alUploadFile.get(i));

            String path = mPath+"/"+ alUploadFile.get(i).getName();

            mRequest = mApi.putFileOverwriteRequest(path, fis,
                    alUploadFile.get(i).length(), new ProgressListener() {
                        @Override
                        public long progressInterval() {
                            // Update the progress bar every half-second or
                            // so
                            return 1;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(long bytes, long total) {
                            publishProgress(bytes);
                        }
                    });

            if (mRequest != null) {
                mRequest.upload();
//              return true;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private boolean exists(String path) {
    try {
         Entry existingEntry = mApi.metadata(path, 1, null, false, null);
         return true;
     } catch (DropboxServerException e) {
        if(e.error == DropboxServerException._404_NOT_FOUND)
            return false;
        throw e;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the result of the upload, you can look at the [`DropboxAPI.Entry`](https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.Entry.html) returned by the [`DropboxAPI.UploadRequest.upload`](https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.UploadRequest.html#upload()) method. E.g., the `Entry`'s `path` will give you the location of the uploaded file.

If you want to check the state of the account at any point in time, when not doing an upload, you can use [`DropboxAPI.metadata`](https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#metadata(java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String)) or [`DropboxAPI.delta`](https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#delta(java.lang.String)).